# Deserialize json string and insert in SQL DB

Tags: vb.net

I have a function which gets json string from jsonblob, deserializers it and returns in dataview. I want to know how can i insert the data from the dataview into my sql database using vb.net

My function is as follows

```
Public Function GetJsonString() As DataView
    Dim dsContactMeta As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim dv As DataView = Nothing
    'url declaration for REST_ContactMeta
    Dim REST_ContactMetaURL As Uri = New Uri("http://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/5420df11e4b00ad1f05ed29b")
    Dim strJSONData As String = ""
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Try
        Dim httpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(REST_ContactMetaURL)
        httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"

        response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

        strJSONData = reader.ReadToEnd
        strJSONData = "[" & strJSONData & "]" 'had to wrap the raw JSON data with brackets for parsing purposes
        Dim myXmlNode As System.Xml.XmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{""root"":" + strJSONData + "}", "root") 'error is thrown if the JSON does not have a root element
        ' Dim myXmlNode As System.Xml.XmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(strJSONData)
        dsContactMeta = New DataSet("Test")
        Try
            dsContactMeta.ReadXml(New XmlNodeReader(myXmlNode))
            If dsContactMeta.Tables("root") Is Nothing Or dsContactMeta.Tables("root").Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Return Nothing 'in case of error return nothing
            Else
                dsContactMeta.Tables("root").Columns("job_id").SetOrdinal(0) 'setting the field name as the first column
                dv = New DataView
                dv.Table = dsContactMeta.Tables("root")
                Return dv
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing 'if for any reason the API has failed connecting to the server or other unknown error then return nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert record into database from DataView, for that you need to read DataView:

```
For Each rowView As DataRowView In dataView
    Debug.Write(item & " ")
    Dim row as DataRow  = rowView.Row;    
    // Do something //
    //insert into tablename(col1,col2,..) values(row['col1'],row['col2'],..)
Next
```